# How to display multiple labels on GUI using Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have created a window in java , where i have added a list box and a submit button. The user can choose an item/itme's from the list box and he/she is supposed to click the submit button.

After submitting, a unique id is getting generated based on the user name , item and unique number. So for each item present in the list, there will be a unique id. Also, I an creating a label using the unique id(user name, item and unique number).

Now, the problem is, when the same user chooses more than one item front the list, the unique id is getting over-written.

My requirement is to display all the unique id's for the selected items (by same user) on UI.

EDIT

`label.setText("Unique Id:"+Uid+""+usernme+""+jcombox.getselecteditem.to string())` This is how I am one label to the frame. This label is unique for an item in the list box. So , for the multiple items selected by the user, how to display/ add these labels to the frame/window.

Comment: Show the snippet of code where you are writing the values to the label. It may be possible to concatenate the new values on to the same label.

Comment: You should post some code (Ideally an SSCCE: http://sscce.org/); otherwise we can only give you vague answers to a vague description.

Answer (score 1):

Use an auxiliary sequential number to your key. You check if the item exist on the list, if exists increment this seqnum and add the to your key, if not just add fill with 0. 
Or use this seq number as a global "counter" always on your key for any "submit".

You may implement you own ListModel, by extending DefaultListModel, to implement these idea.

I may have miss interpreted your problem :) But if not, this will be simple.